# How to compare the user's input with an attribute of an object and get that object?

Tags: java, string, object, enums

So I am coding in java in which I am a newbie, let's say that I have a `class` Place

```
public class Place{
    private String name;
}
```

and I have a `class` Player

```
public class Player{
    private Place location;

    public void goLoc(Place p){
        this.location=p;
    }
}
```

and I need to get from the user where they want to go, and I am using an `enum` to my commands list that the user can use (GO,HELP...etc) so let's say I have these two `objects` :

```
Place r = new Place("Room");
Place r2 = new Place("Room2");
```

when the user will enter for example *go room*, I need to call the `method` `goLoc(r)` but I store the `input` from the user with a `String`.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String loc = in.next();
```

How could I get that `r` `object` by its `attribute` `name`? or is there any other way to do this in a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final List<Place> places = Arrays.asList(r, r2);
final Place selectedPlace = places.stream()
          .filter(p -> p.getName().equals(loc))
          .findFirst()
          .orElse(null);
```

Store all the objects of `Place` in a list and utilize the stream API.